# Using a SQL Function to Format Account info?

Tags: asp.net, sql, vb.net

I have a SQL function that I am calling in my VB.Net code within a display function.  The SQL function will format my account data to include the following results form a Table.

The table data:  "001000011121"  (this is the type of structure the data has before formated)
So the data table data and vb Properties would be called Myaccount, HerAccount, ThisAccount.

Once the data is pulled and then formatted in the VB.net code it will result into a GridDisplay as as: "001.00.001.1121"

The way I have my Public Function in my code is:

```
Public Funcion GetDisplay(_
ByVal dbBass as DataProvider_
,ByVal pps AS TMGDatarequestParms_
,By filter As IFilter_
) As Ilist

Dim strobe As String = CType(parms.OptionalParameters,  DataProvider).Database

Dim sql As BiGSqlBuilder(TABLE)
sql.Select = String.Format("ID, [{0}].dbo.GLForamtAcct(Myaccount) AS [Myaccount], [{0}].dbo.GLFormatAccount(HerAccount) AS [HerAccount], [{0}].dbo.GLFormatAccount(ThisAccount) AS [ThisAccount]", strobe)
```

I left out some of the return code since not necessary.  The only thing I'm concerned is how to format the SQL within the VB.net Code above.  I hope this makes sense I'm new to this whole abstraction stuff.  Any help would be Highly appreciated cause I'm pretty sure how I have it above does not work.

Comment: Suggest implementing your display code in your higher tiers, rather than burdening your database with this business logic.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback p.campbell.  This makes sense! At the same time though would this Select work correctly in VB code?

Comment: Mikey : what is this `BigSqlBuilder` all about?

Comment: Oh that is just my SqlBuilder class in my DATA stuff.  That is where  Like SqlDataProvider, DataProvider, and SqlBuilders are located. So I just use it as a SqlBuilder.  So I created a object sql as New BigSqlBuilder.   I know it sounds corny.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suggest implementing your display code in your higher tiers, rather than burdening your database with this business logic.

It sounds like you're string to use `String.Format()` to insert the table name in your string. This syntax of `database.schema.object` is really only needed if performing cross database calls.

If you really want to use your SQL UDF to perform your formatting, suggest using/formulating a SELECT statement like:

```
 SELECT ID,
        dbo.GLFormatAccount(Acct1) AS Acct1,
        dbo.GLFormatAccount(Acct2) AS Acct2,
        dbo.GLFormatAccount(Acct3) AS Acct3
 FROM MyTable
```

Comment: Okay. I see what you mean. Thank alot for the reply.  I'm still really new to this stuff so your help is highly appreciated.